# How to custom the shape of a JPanel or JLabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm displaying an image in a JLabel. I want to show that image in a circular shape i.e. I want the shape of the JLabel to be a Circle which is Rectangle by default. How to setShape of the JPanel or JLabel?? setUndecorated() and setShape() is defined only for Frame?? Is there any possibility to change the shape of other components like JPanel and JLabel??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A component is always rectangular, however, you can use custom painting and transparency to make the component appear non-rectangular

Take a look at [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FunkyShapedComponent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FunkyShapedComponent();
    }

    public FunkyShapedComponent() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel testPane = new JPanel();
                testPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
                testPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                testPane.add(new FunkyPane());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(testPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FunkyPane extends JPanel {

        public FunkyPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("This is a simple test"));
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets() {
            return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int width = getWidth() - 1;
            int height = getHeight() - 1;

            int radius = Math.min(width, height) / 10;

            Path2D p = new Path2D.Float();
            p.moveTo(0, radius / 2);
            p.curveTo(0, 0, 0, 0, radius / 2, 0);
            p.curveTo(width / 4, radius, width / 4, radius, (width / 2) - radius, radius / 2);
            p.curveTo(width / 2, 0, width / 2, 0, (width / 2) + radius, radius / 2);
            p.curveTo(width - (width / 4), radius, width - (width / 4), radius, width - (radius / 2), 0);
            p.curveTo(width, 0, width, 0, width, radius / 2);

            p.curveTo(width - radius, height / 4, width - radius, height / 4, width - (radius / 2), (height / 2) - radius);
            p.curveTo(width, height / 2, width, height / 2, width - (radius / 2), (height / 2) + radius);
            p.curveTo(width - radius, height - (height / 4), width - radius, height - (height / 4), width, height - (radius / 2));
            p.curveTo(width, height, width, height, width - (radius / 2), height);

            p.curveTo(width - (width / 4), height - radius, width - (width / 4), height - radius, (width / 2) + radius, height - (radius / 2));
            p.curveTo(width / 2, height, width / 2, height, (width / 2) - radius, height - (radius / 2));
            p.curveTo((width / 4), height - radius, (width / 4), height - radius, (radius / 2), height);
            p.curveTo(0, height, 0, height, 0, height - (radius / 2));

            p.curveTo(radius, height - (height / 4), radius, height - (height / 4), (radius / 2), (height / 2) + radius);
            p.curveTo(0, height / 2, 0, height / 2, (radius / 2), (height / 2) - radius);
            p.curveTo(radius, (height / 4), radius, (height / 4), 0, (radius / 2));

            p.closePath();

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fill(p);
            g2d.dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could u tell me how to display a rectangular JPanel in a Circular shape?

Comment: [`Graphics#drawOval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: How would you just build this for a JLabel because currently your classes extends JPanel and then changes the label. What if you want this just to be for a JLabel sot that you could create and instance of it in any form that you build and then set its properties accordingly.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't. The problem is (and the reason I did it this way) is JLabel's paintComponen actually renders the text, meaning if you tried painting on the label after calling super.paintComponet, you'd paint over the text

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to show transparent areas.
You didn't need to set shape, For example, you can use:

```
setOpaque(false);
```

For components has border, you can hide it by:

```
setBorder(null);
```

For button, you can use

```
setBorderPainted(false);
setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: could u tell me how to display a rectangular JPanel in a Circular shape?